# Creating PDF/A with GhostscriptProcessor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ghostscript, pdfa, ghostscript.net

I want to convert a PDF file into PDF/A with GhostscriptProcessor, but the result is a PDF not PDF/A.

```
GhostscriptProcessor gsproc = new GhostscriptProcessor(Properties.Resources.gsdll32);
gsproc.StartProcessing(CreatePDFA(@"C:\test\PDF.pdf", @"C:\test\PDFA.pdf"), new GsStdio());
```

And the method:

```
CreateTestArgs(string inputPath, string outputPath)
{
    List<string> gsArgs = new List<string>();
    gsArgs.Add("-dPDFA");
    gsArgs.Add("-dBATCH");
    gsArgs.Add("-dNOPAUSEgsArgs");
    gsArgs.Add("-sDEVICE=pdfwrite");
    gsArgs.Add(@"-sOutputFile=" + outputPath);
    gsArgs.Add(@"-f" + inputPath);
    return gsArgs.ToArray();
}
```

If I use gswin32.exe from the commandline the result is a PDF/A file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First switch is ignored. You need to add dummy switch at position 0 so the code will look like:

```
string[] CreateTestArgs(string inputPath, string outputPath)
{
    List<string> gsArgs = new List<string>();
    gsArgs.Add("-notused");
    gsArgs.Add("-dPDFA");
    gsArgs.Add("-dBATCH");
    gsArgs.Add("-dNOPAUSEgsArgs");
    gsArgs.Add("-sDEVICE=pdfwrite");
    gsArgs.Add(@"-sOutputFile=" + outputPath);
    gsArgs.Add(@"-f" + inputPath);
    return gsArgs.ToArray();
}
```